# The error about “A stream table does not support direct access. Please use sql query to retrieve data”

Tags: dolphindb

I create a stream table:

```py
colName=["time","x"]
colType=["timestamp","int"]
t = streamTable(100:0, colName, colType);
enableTableShareAndPersistence(table=t, tableName=`st, cacheSize=1200000)
```

Then I insert two pieces of data in it:

```py
time = 0..1 + now()
x = 10 20
data = table(time, x)
st.append!(data )
Select the data in time column:
st.time
```

The error displays:

```py
A stream table does not support direct access. Please use sql query to retrieve data
```

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

The stream table (streamTable) can be understood as a special memory table, currently does not support st.time access methods, but supports SQL query access methods, as follows:

```py
select time from st
```

result:
|time|
|----|
|2021.08.06T12:08:59.504|
|2021.08.06T12:08:59.505|